# Time complexity of if statement with log n comparison

Tags: java, time, complexity-theory

trying to wrap my head around big O notation and time complexity, finding it hard to understand how if statements affect the time complexity.

In the function below, the operation inside the if statement will only run once, because it will only go inside the If operation when binarySearch returns true for the input.

But the if statement will go O(n) times, using binarySearch which is log n.

Is the time complexity here O(n) or O(n*logn)? would love to have an explanation of the correct answer, since i find it hard to understand how the log n comparison of the if statement affect the time complexity of the method.

```
public static boolean what2 (int [][] m, int val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i ++)
    {
        if (binarySearch(m, val, i))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Does it help to remember that "big-O" is a measure of *worst case* time complexity?

Comment: ***I forgot to add that this function gets arrays that have sorted coulmns*** i just try to understand how the time complexity of the binarySearch comparison affects the time complexity of the whole function. if the comparison of binary search happens n times, but every time it the comparison takes log n times, what does it mean?

Comment: That was implied by the applicability of a binarySearch.

Comment: You *really* don't know how long it would take to do something that takes log n time n times?

Comment: to Scott, yes, i REALLY didn't knew, i'm in the beginning of complexity and trying to wrap my head around it, i study alone and saw different things that were confusing me so i wanted to post here to get clarification... thanks for the help, and the sarcasm, i guess?

Comment: Complexity *can* be confusing, but this is about as straight-forward as it gets.  You said it yourself: "binary search happens n times, but every time the comparison takes log n": so n log n's, or n * log n.

Answer (score 1):

How much time does the loop run?  r times - O(r) - the number of rows.

**for each** row, perform a binary search - O(logc) - c is the length of the row

we are looking for the **worst-case**, in the worst case we never stop by entering the if, so we will iterate over all the rows

so the total run time is O(r*log(c)) [r - num of rows, c - num of colums]

note: if r = c = n then the run time can be simplified as O(nlogn)